# Sentiment analysis in Spanish with google cloud natural language api

Tags: google-cloud-nl

it looks that the new API gives sentiment analysis in English, but not in Spanish, there is any help about that? When is it expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've just made [an overview of 15 Sentiment Analysis APIs](https://blog.inten.to/cloud-sentiment-analysis-vendor-overview-32d4bdaaf0c3), 8 of them support Spanish so far:

- [Sentiment Analysis by nlu at Algorithmia](https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/nlp/SentimentAnalysis/docs) (based on NLTK)
- [Amazon Web Services Comprehend](https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend/)
- [Google Cloud Natural Language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/)
- [IBM Watson NLU](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/natural-language-understanding/)
- [Meaning Cloud Sentiment Analysis](https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/sentiment-analysis)
- [Microsoft Cognitive Services Text Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/)
- [Repustate Text Analytics](https://www.repustate.com/text-analytics-api/)
- [TheSay PreCeive](http://www.theysay.io/product/preceive/)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Google Research NLP PM here.

We are planning to launch sentiment in Spanish, but don't yet have a timeline. One thing you can do in the meantime is run the text through the Translate API, which will fail badly for syntax but actually works reasonably well for Sentiment.

What kind of data are you planning to send through?

Edit: This is launched, and you can use it now.

Comment: We develop ehealth projects, and we would like to add sentiment to doctors comments. Also we are planning it for twitter analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Great progress has been made for sentiment analysis in Spanish since you asked your question 6 years ago. Today, you have very good Hugging Face Transformer based models, fine-tuned for sentiment analysis in Spanish. For example see these models:

```
- https://huggingface.co/sagorsarker/codeswitch-spaeng-sentiment-analysis-lince
- https://huggingface.co/daveni/twitter-xlm-roberta-emotion-es
- https://huggingface.co/nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment
```

There are also very good APIs for sentiment analysis in Spanish like
[NLP Cloud](https://nlpcloud.io?utm_source=so&utm_campaign=e411103c-dd8e-11eb-ba80-2242ac130007) or https://www.repustate.com/spanish-sentiment-analysis/

(disclaimer: I'm a developer of NLP Cloud)